# Added Column to the Database is NOT getting retrieved in the View

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I am doing a online ASP.net MVC5 course from udemy.I added a new column to my Table using EF migration.

**Name Column Added**

```
namespace Vidly.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class AddNameToMembershipTypes : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.MembershipTypes","Name",c => c.String(nullable:false));
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.MembershipTypes","Name");
        }
    }
}
```

Then I updated my database for this migration.

**Screen Shot for Confirmation**

[image]

Customer and MembershipTypes Tables  have one-to-one relationship and I am able to retrieve MembershipTypes fields from the Customer Table.

The only problem is that The new column "Name" I just added to the MembershipTypes as I described at the very top is NOT getting retrieved from the View.

**Following is The Visual confirmation(Although I tried to add Name but got error)**

[image]

**When I forcefully tried to access Name I got following**

[image]

I am Not getting why I am Not being able to access Name Field as I have added some values too using migration and updated my database.
My feeling is that the link between Customer and  MembershipTypes needs to be updated somehow but I donot know how?

Comment: It might sound stupid, but did you add `Name` property to your `MembershipType` class? I'm asking because you've shown your db table, but not the entity model (class).

Comment: No I did not..............and It might not sound stupid as I am indeed stupid...........thanks bro.

Comment: Please also tell me as I started working using EF code first from just today that how would I update my model now when I added that field to my MembershipType.cs?

Comment: With Code First, you usually modify your model (add properties, new classes etc.), then use `Add-Migration` command to create migration for you. Basically you never create migrations or modify database manually. To verify if the model and db are in sync, you can execute another `Add-Migration` command - if the generated migration has empty `Up` and `Down` methods, then you are ok (and you can simply delete the generated `cs` file from the project).

Comment: Looking at your migration, you might need to decorate the `Name` property with `Required` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes you have in your `AddNameToMembershipTypes` is only for updating your database schema. That will not automatically update your entity class. You still need to add the new property to your `MemberShipType` class.

```
public class MembershipType
{
   public string Name { set;get;}  // This one here

   // Your existing properties here
   public int DurationInMonths { set;get; }
}
```